# NoSuchMethodError org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject()Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, itext, digital-signature

I'm getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject()Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive;

This is my TestSign.java

```
    package com.test.sign;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAppearance;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfFormField;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalSignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.CryptoStandard;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalDigest;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PrivateKeySignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature;

public class TestSign {

    /** The resulting PDF */
    public static String ORIGINAL = "C://results/xmlworker/test3.pdf";
    /** The resulting PDF */
    public static String SIGNED1 = "results/part3/chapter12/signed_1.pdf";
    /** The resulting PDF */
    public static String SIGNED2 = "C://results/xmlworker/test3yfguhik.pdf";

    /** One of the resources. */
    public static final String RESOURCE
        = "resources/img/1t3xt.gif";

    /**
     * A properties file that is PRIVATE.
     * You should make your own properties file and adapt this line.
     */
    //public static String PATH = "c:/home/blowagie/key.properties";
    /** Some properties used when signing. */
    //public static Properties properties = new Properties();

    /**
     * Creates a PDF document.
     * @param filename the path to the new PDF document
     * @throws DocumentException 
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public void createPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
        PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.createSignature(writer);
        field.setWidget(new Rectangle(72, 732, 144, 780), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);
        field.setFieldName("mySig");
        field.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
        field.setPage();
        field.setMKBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
        field.setMKBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
        PdfAppearance tp = PdfAppearance.createAppearance(writer, 72, 48);
        tp.rectangle(0.5f, 0.5f, 71.5f, 47.5f);
        tp.stroke();
        field.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, tp);
        writer.addAnnotation(field);
        // step 5
        document.close();
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates a PDF file src with the file dest as result
     * @param src the original PDF
     * @param dest the resulting PDF
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException 
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws DocumentException 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     * @throws KeyStoreException 
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public void signPdf(String src, String dest, boolean certified, boolean graphic) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
        // private key and certificate

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream("C://results/xmlworker/Test.pfx"), "10111995".toCharArray());
        String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, "10111995".toCharArray());
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
        // reader and stamper
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(ORIGINAL);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), '\0');
        // appearance
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setVisibleSignature("mySig");
        appearance.setReason("It's personal.");
        appearance.setLocation("Foobar");
        if (certified)
            appearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
        if (graphic) {
            appearance.setSignatureGraphic(Image.getInstance(RESOURCE));
            appearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC);
        }
        // signature
        ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256", "BC");
        ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     *
     * @param    args    no arguments needed
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception {
        //Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        TestSign signatures = new TestSign();
        signatures.createPdf(ORIGINAL);
        //signatures.signPdf(ORIGINAL, SIGNED1, false, false);
        signatures.signPdf(ORIGINAL, SIGNED2, true, false);
    }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>exemple</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>exemple Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.56</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.56</version>
        </dependency>    
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I've tried all versions of bcprov-jdk15on and bcmail-jdk15on , Can you help me please , i'm stuck for like a week in this problem?

I've copied the code from this [Exemple](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-12)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the wrong version of BouncyCastle for this version of iText.

I recommened that you use a combination of iText 5.5.11 and BouncyCastle 1.49, as you can see in the iText POM: https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/5.5.11/itext/pom.xml

```
  <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.11</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>1.49</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>1.49</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Also make sure that you only have one version of BouncyCastle.

Comment: I am also getting below error 
`
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier.equals(org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive)'
`